# how can i center a nested div

Tags: css, html, centering

i am trying to center a nested `div` vertically to create a simple math problem (with fractions) and im not sure how to do it (without hardcoding it based on the parent div height)

what i have so far looks like this:

[image]

i am trying to center the plus sign ( `div .plus` )

### html

```
<div class = "problem">
    <div class = "fraction">
        5
        <hr />
        6
    </div>
    <div class= plus>
        +
    </div>
    <div class = "fraction">
        5
        <hr />
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.fraction{
    width: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.problem > *{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/NT6d5/1/)

Comment: Also check this, I found it very useful http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `inline-block` instead of `float`:

```
.problem > *{
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/NT6d5/2/

Answer (score 1):

Another way is with the `display:table` property.

```
.problem{
     display:table;
}

.problem > *{
    padding:5px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3hfL/1/